# Memory failure while trying to train a logistic regression model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I'm getting this failure:

File "C:\Users\ophirbh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\special_logsumexp.py", line 112, in logsumexp
    tmp = np.exp(a - a_max)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (950028, 45) and data type float64

for that code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

X, y = datasets.load_svmlight_file('converted_features')
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0, solver = 'lbfgs', multi_class = 
'multinomial',max_iter=2).fit(X,y)
print(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, scoring='recall_macro', cv = 5))
```

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you seem to have insufficient memory, you can use [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) for quick experimentations without getting into any memory issues.